# How to get secure url canonical in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, url, backend, canonical

In the Magento backend, under

> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations

It adds category and product pages to the canonical url automatically, however the url is not secure and my entire site is in `HTTPS`. I would like to know how I can proceed to be able to add `secure URL` in canonical or I would like to know if doing what I described in the question, it already adds the `secure URL (HTTPS)` automatically in the canonical tag.

I've already done a lot of research on this and all the options explained follow the same steps I described in the question. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If your base URLs in configuration  are set to `https` , canonical URLs are set to `https` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the canonical url to use the secure url is simple.

If `HTTPS` is enabled and configured correctly in:

```
System -> Configuration -> Web -> HTTPS
```

In url base, the site link is on https://your_url.com, the canonical url will use the `secure url(HTTPS)`, otherwise it will base url being `HTTP`.